# Get current AWS profile using .Net SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

In a C# project being executed on the development machine, I want to get the AWS region for my current AWS profile. I've seen the [credential and profile resolution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html) documentation and would rather not reimplement this if I can avoid it. In bash I would use:

```sh
Region=$(aws configure get region)
```

Is there some call in the AWS .Net SDK to do the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created an AWS client object for some service, you can access the region for the default user through the Config property of the client object.

This two-line example creates a client using the default credentials and then displays the RegionEndpoint value on the console:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client();
Console.WriteLine(client.Config.RegionEndpoint);
```

This code uses the AWS SDK for .NET version 3.7 and .NET Core 5. Here is a link to the API documentation for the IClientConfig interface so you can see what other information is available: [IClientConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TIClientConfig.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but in case anyone was looking for a slightly different answer (like I was :-), I wanted to share.

Another possible goal is to read the Region from a named profile outside the context of any service client.
The equivalent in the AWS CLI might be:

```
aws configure get region --profile my-named-profile
```

You might want to do this, for example, so that you can use the Region setting while creating a service client.

The following code (or similar) will accomplish this goal:

```
using Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement;

static RegionEndpoint ReadRegionEnpoint(string profileName)
{
    var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
    if(!chain.TryGetProfile(profileName, out var profile))
        throw new Exception($"Failed to find the {profileName} profile");
    return profile.Region;
}
```

**Note**: Be aware that this procedure gives the region that is explicitly configured for the named profile. It doesn't take into account any sort of fallback region search.

Hope this is helpful.